# Estimating backward diffraction from a corner

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

I'm trying to estimate the proportion of light reflected back to the source by an outside corner, as in the simulated picture below:
[image: Diffraction reflection by corner][1]

Unfortunately, I don't know of any approximation that would make this tractable. Frensnel and Frauenhoffer diffraction both look like the require the observation point to be on the opposite side of the screen as far as I can tell.

In my case, I only care about the intensity returning to the source as a function of angle and distance. Unlike the image, my source is approximately a plane wave (I couldn't fit one in the simulator). I made the simulated wave a pulse to make it easier to see the reflection.

I believe this is similar to the "wedge diffraction" problem, but most diffraction treatments I know of only work going away from the source.

An example problem:

> I have a laser beam with 500nm wavelength, 200mW of power illuminating a circle with a diameter of 2mm,  with a divergence of 0.005 mrad. θ is 0.5 rad, and the source is 40cm away from the corner. The laser is pointed directly at the corner, so there is no out of plane tilt. Assume the corner is an ideal conductor.
>
> What is the intensity of the light reflected to the source in W/m^2?

The closest published thing I can find is [this paper](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/viewmedia.cfm?uri=oe-18-3-2588&seq=0), but it has arbitrary intensity units, and only covers the case where θ=0.

[1]:Created using Paul Falstad's simulator www.falstad.com